# Manually remove record from ember data store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember and ember data in my application . How can we remove manually a record from the store in Ember . Currently i am pushing the record to store using push method . I have some issues with ember data save , so i used ajax function for save . Is there any method like record.remove()?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`record.unloadRecord()` or `store.unloadRecord(record)`, additionally you can remove all records for a type, `store.unloadAll(type)`

Comment: If i find a record(store.find) and then change the value of the record after update(inside success function of ajax call) , then if click remove button , it will not unload from the store. So i used deleteRecord()? it works for me ... but i don't know wheather it is correct way or not?

Comment: deleteRecord marks a record as deleted, if you then tried to save it would send a DELETE request to your server.  unloadRecord is the correct way.  If you'd like, you can set up a jsbin (emberjs.jsbin.com) to show me your issue.

Comment: No , i am not using save method because i am getting some issues , so i switched back to ajax.

Comment: Worth noting that unloadRecord is a private API method, so use w/ caution.