# What's the longetivity of DS record once fetched?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

To me it looks like they live until the page is refreshed or am I doing something wrong, can someone throw some light on this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It lives until the page is refreshed or you manually remove the it from the store.

[Manually remove record from ember data store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407096/manually-remove-record-from-ember-data-store/20407452#20407452)

Comment: see link to previous stack overflow question.