# Ember.js "calling set on destroyed object" Error after call to unloadRecord

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Within a sessioning system for a project I'm working on, I'm calling `unloadRecord` on a record like so:

```
user.unloadRecord();
```

I'm not calling `destroyRecord` because I want to manually unload the record from the store without persisting it to the server. Removing the record from the store in this manner works perfectly, but when I log into the same account--which requires loading the same user record from the server and inserting it into the store manually using `store.push`--I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object     ember.js:3902
```

Again, this occurs at the following line *after* calling `user.unloadRecord()`:

```
var user = this.store.push("user", response.user);
```

Where the `response` is the JSON payload returned by the `POST` request to /session, an example of which is shown here:

```
{
    "sessionToken":"f7a7247467b08818ead27441838df30fed0e0a79",
    "user": {
        "id":"5499bf5b7f25680761c9df7a",
        "email":"test@gmail.com",
        "accounts": [/* [account ids] */],
        "syncPaths":[/* [sync path ids] */]
    }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid this error?

**UPDATE**:

In response to requests to see more of the code, [here](https://github.com/brad-ross-35/pype/blob/master/src/webClientService/client/js/services/session-manager.js) is the file containing the `unloadRecord` call, and [here](https://github.com/brad-ross-35/pype/blob/master/src/webClientService/client/js/controllers/login.js) is the file containing the `store.push` call.

**UPDATE 2**:
I included an example of the JSON payload returned by a POST request to /session, as requested. Here is the model for a `user`:

```
DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr("string"),
    accounts: DS.hasMany("account"),
    syncPaths: DS.hasMany("syncPaths")
});
```

Comment: Can you post more of the code? Where do you call destroy?

Comment: Why are you required to re-load the user record manually? I'd think once you unload the record you would need to fetch from the server.

Comment: @Oren, there isn't any other relevant code to the error--everything else nearby these lines doesn't do anything related to loading `user` records. I've updated the question with links to the appropriate files on Github. 

I never call `destroy` because I use `unloadRecord` as explained in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407096/manually-remove-record-from-ember-data-store) stack overflow answer.

Comment: @Matt, It's a long story, but when the user logs in, I make a POST request to /session with the user's credentials. The request returns both a session token and a `user` record, which I then push manually into the store as explained in the question.

Comment: Is using the RESTAdapter to load the user an option? Possibly by creating a LoginRESTAdapter to handle the session/user api requests instead of using the ajax call? I can't be sure, but it feels like the combination of the Ajax call and pushing into the store is what's making Ember flaky (it thinks there's a RESTAdapter, but you have this other ajax call happening and resulting in stuff being pushed into the store).

Comment: What version of Ember Data are you using?

Comment: @Matt, the only issue is I don't want to make a DELETE /user request to the server because semantically that should delete the user on the server-side. I simply want to remove the user from the store on the client when a user logs out.

Comment: @Kingpin2k, I'm using 1.0.0 beta 14

Comment: It doesn't appear to be an issue with the version (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dimakuquno/1/edit), do you have a reference lying around that's trying to set a property on the user?

Comment: @Kingpin2k, There aren't any other references lying around.

Comment: It might be some sort of race condition, it'll be difficult to track down just looking at the code, would you mind trying to replicate using the jsbin provided?

Comment: Maybe some context of what the user model looks like and the user json might help as well.

Comment: @Kingpin2k extra information has been added.

Answer (score 3):

I have been struggling with something similar, albeit with `unloadAll()`.
Someone else suggested this, so maybe it will help you.

In your source code, `ember.js` or `ember.debug.js` if running locally, find this line:

`Ember['default'].assert('calling set on destroyed object', !obj.isDestroyed);`

and change it to:

`Ember['default'].assert("calling set ('" + keyName + "') on destroyed object", !obj.isDestroyed);`

Then you will see the property being set, and it may help you track down where in your code it's hanging up. For me, `keyName` is just "length" which isn't very helpful.

Comment: have you found the solution to your issue? Having the exact same error where `keyName` is just `length`.

Comment: any news on the topic?

Comment: I actually just found the answer! The thing you need to do is call `this.store.unloadAll(<model>)` for each relationship model first.